# Subdirectories files and ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, .htaccess

Sorry if this topic has been talked about a lot but I'm working on a router with ajax and I have a problem when I load .html files that are in a subdirectory.
When I try to load the file "/portfolio/project.html" my container load the index.html. Why?!
Could be a problem with the file .htaccess?

**EDIT**
My .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]

    # Disable Automatic Directory detection
    DirectorySlash Off

    # Hide extension
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html

</ifModule>
```

Comment: Yes, is a real file.

Comment: Does it load `/portfolio/index.html` or `/index.html`?

Comment: Rename this .htaccess and retest to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Strange, XMLHttpRequest add one directory to the path.
responseURL: "http://localhost:8888/Router/portfolio/portfolio/project.html"

Comment: If problem remains after renaming this .htaccess then problem is somewhere isn't it?

Comment: You might have some error in your AJAX code.